# List of classes in an assembly

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, .net-assembly

I've a DLL assembly, in which there are various classes. Each class has around 50-100 members and 4-5 functions. How can I create a list of all the classes and their respective members using a VB.NET program?

I need to show to the user for performing an operation using a particular class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) and
 [System.Type.GetMembers()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmembers.aspx)

--larsw

Comment: -1 for not including any explanation beyond the links.

Comment: The first link no longer exists

Answer (score 17):

Assuming that you've your assembly loaded to thisAsm (in this ex I'm using the executing assembly),

This will get you all non abstract classes:

```
Assembly thisAsm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
List<Type> types = thisAsm.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract).ToList();
```

And this will get you all classes that implements a specific interface.

(Eg. If you need to get only the classes that implements IYourInterface, then)

```
Assembly thisAsm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
List<Type> types = thisAsm.GetTypes().Where
            (t => ((typeof(IYourInterface).IsAssignableFrom(t) 
                 && t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract))).ToList();
```

Once you've this list of items, you can show the members of each type, by calling the GetProperties() and GetMethods() on each member of the types list.

Comment: It should still be pretty straightforward to convert the C# to VB.

Comment: +2 for providing an actual answer with actual code. -1 for not translating it to VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all type that inherits from [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in VB.net:

```
Dim thisAsm As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Dim types As List(Of Type) = thisAsm.GetTypes().Where(Function(t) t.BaseType = GetType(Form)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is vb.net version based on @amazedsaint answer:

```
Dim thisAsm As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Dim types As List(Of Type) = thisAsm
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(Function(t) t.IsClass AndAlso Not t.IsAbstract).ToList()

Dim thisAsm As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Dim types As List(Of Type) = thisAsm
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(Function(t) ((GetType(IYourInterface).IsAssignableFrom(t) AndAlso t.IsClass AndAlso Not t.IsAbstract))).ToList()
```

Answer (score -2):

Many examples are on the web. Here's [one](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2008/12/reflection-in-c-list-of-class-name.html) (in [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) though).

Comment: -1 for not including any explanation beyond the links.