# How to get type of a derived class from another derived class

Tags: c#, derived-class

I have the (pseudo) code:

```
public class GlobalClass
{
    public GlobalClass()
    {
        var x = this.GetType().Name // Returns "Channels"
        // WHAT TO DO HERE?
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And using this code:

```
public class Channels : GlobalClass
{
    public Channels()
    {

    }

    public class Channel : BaseClass
    {

    }
}
```

Where the comment is (// WHAT TO DO HERE?), I want to get the runtime type of BaseClass,
where in my sample code should return `Channel`.

I am open to different approaches, but only if it's accompanied with an explanation why I should change the code.

Comment: What are you trying to do, actually? Why do you think you need this type? What if `GlobalClass` inherits a different class? Which class type will you need in that case?

Comment: i have 3-5 class which have the same properties and methods, all i want to do is stop repeating my code in each and every class. i know its a little over my head, but i am willing to learn :)

Comment: why the Close request? there is no duplicate for this question and i found no information googling it. please explain.

Comment: *i want to do is stop repeating my code in each and every class*: Yes, inheritance will help you achieve this. But there is rarely a need to access the **type** of the base class when doing this. What do you want to do with this type?

Comment: @Groo the data for those classes are loaded from files, which reside each in the appropiate folder name ( the folder name is the same as the class ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection like this:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

...

```
public class GlobalClass
{
    public GlobalClass()
    {
        Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ().GetTypes ();
        foreach ( Type t in types )
        {
            if ( t.BaseType == typeof ( BaseClass ) )
            {
                Console.WriteLine ( "I found a class " + t.Name + " that subclass BaseClass" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See also Stack Overflow question *[List of classes in an assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397435)*.

Comment: this works, but are there any disadvantages i should be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a generic class here, something like:

```
    public class GlobalClass<T> where T : BaseClass
    {
        public GlobalClass()
        {
            var theType = typeof(T);    //you got it
        }
    }
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class Channel : BaseClass { }
    public class Channels : GlobalClass<Channel> { }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.71).aspx) operator is just for that purpose.

[`getType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) method with class `Type` can also be used.

```
class Example 
{
    static void ShowTypeInfo (object o) 
    {  
        Console.WriteLine ("type name = {0}, 
                            full type name = {1}", o.GetType(), 
                            o.GetType().FullName ); 
    }

    public static void Main()
    { 
        long longType = 99; 
        Example example= new Example(); 

        ShowTypeInfo (example); 
        ShowTypeInfo (longType); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the runtime type of anything, you first need an object instance to get the type from. So with your given structure, that's not possible.

There are two possible approaches:

1. Add a `BaseClass` parameter to the constructor of your GlobalClass:

   ```
   public class GlobalClass
   {
       public GlobalClass(BaseClass data)
       {
           var dataType = data == null ? null : data.GetType();
           // do something with the type
       }
   }

   public class Channels : GlobalClass
   {
       public Channels(Channel data) : base(data)
       {

       }

       public class Channel : BaseClass
       {

       }
   }
   ```
2. Pass the type to the constructor directly:

   ```
   public class GlobalClass
   {
       public GlobalClass(Type actualType)
       {
           Debug.Assert(typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(actualType));
       }
   }

   public class Channels : GlobalClass
   {
       public Channels() : base(typeof(Channel))
       {

       }

       public class Channel : BaseClass
       {

       }
   }
   ```

If the structure for some reason doesn't allow generics here (as [Danny Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9077179/880802) suggested), I'd personally prefer the second approach, since that doesn't need an actual instance.