# List of classes in an assembly C#

Tags: c#, .net, class, .net-assembly

I want to get the list of classes in an assembly, as an output i want a List[Interface] not a List[string], as "Interface" is the interface from which inherits the classes of my assembly. I don't know if my question makes sense but if any one has the answer i would very much thankful.
I already tried this solution: [List of classes in an assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397435/list-of-classes-in-an-assembly), but it gives a list[string] containing the classes namesso it didn't help because i need the list of the classes that inherits from my interface.
Thank you and have a nice day all :)

As an edit for my question, I used activator.createinstance(type t) to create instances of my classes so here is the code :

```
   Assembly assembly = typeof(Interface1<double, double>).Assembly;

   List<Interface> Classes = new List<Interface>();

   foreach (Type type in assembly.GetExportedTypes())

   {
      var Attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes<FilterAttribute>();
      //select the classes with attribute [Filter]

      if (Attributes.Any())

      {
                TypeOfFilters.Add(type);

      }

      foreach (var i in TypeOfFilters)

      {
            var inst = Activator.CreateInstance(i);

            Classes.Add((Interface) inst);


      }

   }
```

i get the error "System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly"

Comment: `but it didn't work for me! `. OK. How?

Comment: This is either a dupe of the question you linked to, unless you specify how it didn't work. Or it is Off topic because you haven't provided all of the relevant information in your post. Consider adding a [MCVE] so it is clear what your issue is. You can [edit] your question to add this information in.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn´t work"? Do you get an exception? Eunexpected results? What did you expect instead? Please show what you´ve tried any where you´re stuck.

Comment: it gave me a List<type>, it's not what i'm looking for.

Comment: @ABIR And what are you looking for?

Comment: @ABIR: If I get you correctly, you say you have an interface `IX` that all classes within your assembly inherit from. Thus, you want a `List<IX>` as a result. However, that would mean each discovered class would have to be *instantiated*, so you would get a list with *one instance of each type in your assembly* - is that what you want?

Comment: Could you paste the exact code you're using? For example, your List is named `classes`, but later referenced as `Classes`. Also, what is the full exception you are getting, including assembly names? The name usually comes after "Could not load file or assembly"

Comment: I finally solved the issue i added a parametreless constructor to each class that inherits from my Interface, as for the error  "System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly" it was due to the fact that "System.ComponentModel.Composition.CodePlex
"  copy local was set to false.  So both methods work perfectly!! sorry for the delay response and thank you very much @ColinM.

Comment: Excellent news, glad you got it sorted & enjoy your plugin system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little class I whipped up some weeks back when I was bored, this does what you're asking of - if I understand the question correctly.

Your applications must implement IPlugin, and must be dropped in a "Plugins" folder in the executing directory.

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    void Initialize();
}
public class PluginLoader
{
    public List<IPlugin> LoadPlugins()
    {
        List<IPlugin> plugins = new List<IPlugin>();

        IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Plugins"),
            "*.dll",
            SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        foreach (var dllFile in files)
        {
            Assembly loaded = Assembly.LoadFile(dllFile);

            IEnumerable<Type> reflectedType =
                loaded.GetExportedTypes().Where(p => p.IsClass && p.GetInterface(nameof(IPlugin)) != null);

            plugins.AddRange(reflectedType.Select(p => (IPlugin) Activator.CreateInstance(p)));
        }

        return plugins;
    }
}
```

Following from Paul's recommendation in the comments, here's a variation using MEF, referencing the `System.ComponentModel.Composition` namespace.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;

    public interface IPlugin
    {
        void Initialize();
    }
    class Program
    {
        private static CompositionContainer _container;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Plugins")));

            _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            IPlugin plugin = null;
            try
            {
                _container.ComposeParts();

                // GetExports<T> returns an IEnumerable<Lazy<T>>, and so Value must be called when you want an instance of the object type.
                plugin = _container.GetExports<IPlugin>().ToArray()[0].Value;
            }
            catch (CompositionException compositionException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(compositionException.ToString());
            }

            plugin.Initialize();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

and the DLL file - also referencing the `System.ComponentModel.Composition` namespace to set the `ExportAttribute`

```
namespace FirstPlugin
{
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

    [Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
    public class NamePlugin : IPlugin
    {
        public void Initialize() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is what ABIR is wanting I would use MEF(Managed Extensibility Framework) instead of creating the instances by yourself via Activator-class. MEF mechanism was created for the purpose of loading and instantiating classes that implement a specified interface at runtime and is a safer approach.

Comment: Thanks for that @PaulWeiland, I've only ever used the `Activator` and `Delegate` approaches, but will have to take a look at MEF too

Comment: I'm using it for a Plug-In-Framework im working on. Hacked some code together with Activator.CreateInstance first until a workmate of mine directed me to MEF. That made my life a lot easier.

Comment: For Op: Here's a nice little brief tutorial on MEF, the benefits are definitely seen here rather than using Activators and creating your own logic to pick up your plugins from a specific directory. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188054/An-Introduction-to-Managed-Extensibility-Framework#4

Comment: thank you for the answers @ColiM , this is exactly what i need. but i get the error "System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly" the problem i think  is with "Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()" is gives me a totally different directory "C:\Users\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs14" instead of the one containing the assembly.

Comment: Ensure the plugins folder is the correct path, and possibly debug the path

Comment: Also, which code above are you using, MEF or Activator? If you're getting the ReSharper directory then are you creating a ReSharper plugin?

Comment: i already tried activator and it gives me the error "System.MissingMethodException : No parameterless constructor defined for this object. " francly i couldn't resolve it i didn't understand what is the problem so i tried with the other solution ! where exactly do i need to create the plugins folder?

Comment: The MissingMethodException would have been due to a direct copy of the code I posted, so you essentially would have been calling `Initialize` on your plugin class - which doesn't implement that method. The architecture of the plugins system I think is down to you ultimately, but the plugins folder can be anywhere as long as you have a link to that path **and** it contains the Dll files which have the classes that implement your plugin interface **AND** use the `ExportAttribute` to allow the `CompositionContainer` to import.

Comment: @ABIR, let's continue the discussion here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142754/list-of-classes-in-an-assembly-c

Comment: @ColinM, i'm sorry it seems that i can not speak in chat rooms because I must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk there, i only have 15 :/

Comment: Still can't i'm sorry!! my reutation is still 15 in chat rooms!!

Comment: @ABIR Can you update your question and provide more information as to how you're using the code above?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly it should be something like that:

```
var list = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => typeof(IYourInterface).IsAssignableFrom(x)).ToList();
```